# Is there a word that means "theorem (in context), possibly with free variables"?

Tags: terminology

Suppose I write down some assumptions...

1. $a < b$
2. $b < c$

   ...and deduce some stuff...
3. $a < c$
4. $a \neq c$

is there a word that covers both my assumptions, and the things I've deduced?

For example, if my assumptions had no free variables, I'd feel comfortable calling 1 & 2 "axioms" and calling 1 through to 4 "theorems" or "demonstrated theorems."

Comment: I think a slang term for the assumptions is the "givens": given conditions (A), (B), ...  The text as a whole might be called a "proposition", where it includes what is given and what can be deduced from it.  Then the proof is a separate text.

Comment: @abiessu, thanks, that sounds reasonable.